# How to filter matching records in a multidimentional unindexed Javascript array?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I'm using Google scripting interface to write a script which manipulates the related spreadsheet using Javascript.

i have a sheet which contains only transactions and I've loaded the data into an array. The array is called **allTrans()** and looks like this:

```
[
  [Account No., Acc. Name, O/R, Ack. Receipt, Date, Description, Category, Credit, Debit, P. Method, Chq. Date, Chq. No., Bank Name, Deposited],
  [0001, Snow, , , Thu Apr 12 20:24:41 GMT+08:00 2018, H.O.A. dues for month of April, HOA Dues, , 400.0, , , , , ],
  [0002, Two, , , Thu Apr 12 20:24:41 GMT+08:00 2018, H.O.A. dues for month of April, HOA Dues, , 400.0, , , , , ],
  [0003, Three, , , Thu Apr 12 20:24:41 GMT+08:00 2018, H.O.A. dues for month of April, HOA Dues, , 400.0, , , , , ],
  [0004, Four, , , Thu Apr 12 20:24:41 GMT+08:00 2018, Monthly accrued interest @ 12% per annum (1% per month) on ageing balance more than 3 months., Int. Charge, , 4.0, , , , , ],
  [0004, Four, , , Thu Apr 12 20:24:42 GMT+08:00 2018, H.O.A. dues for month of April, HOA Dues, , 400.0, , , , , ],
  [0005, Five, , , Thu Apr 12 20:24:42 GMT+08:00 2018, Monthly accrued interest @ 12% per annum (1% per month) on ageing balance more than 3 months., Int. Charge, , 8.0, , , , , ],
  [0005, Five, , , Thu Apr 12 20:24:42 GMT+08:00 2018, H.O.A. dues for month of April, HOA Dues, , 400.0, , , , , ],
  [0006, Six, , , Thu Apr 12 20:24:43 GMT+08:00 2018, Monthly accrued interest @ 12% per annum (1% per month) on ageing balance more than 3 months., Int. Charge, , 12.0, , , , , ],
  [0006, Six, , , Thu Apr 12 20:24:43 GMT+08:00 2018, H.O.A. dues for month of April, HOA Dues, , 400.0, , , , , ]
]
```

I need to be able to filter all transactions belonging to a certain account number (let's say account number '0004', so that I can include them on their statement of account but I can't find any examples of how to do this if you don't have key:value pairs to work with.

Need someone to point me in the right direction please, to get me started.

Comment: `The array is called allTrans()` --> No... this is a function, not an array. And the array you provided here is not valid. Values need to be in quotes

Comment: Oh? It was created using "var allTrans =sheet.getDataRange().getValues();" and I've been accessing it with allTrans[3][0] (for example).

Comment: Yes. `allTrans` not `allTrans()`

Comment: Ok. Really appreciate everyones inputs. I'll be back after researching why my array is not valid. Will choose an answer then. Thanks.

Comment: It seems that I'm using the Google features getDataRange().getValues() correctly and it works for most purposes. I'll write a function to reformat the Javascript object into a valid array, so I can use Taki's answer below.

Comment: That's fixed it. I had declared it already but it was only when I stopped passing it that it worked. Glad I asked! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter on the `Account No` ( the first element of the array )

```js
let arr = [
  ['Account No.',' Acc. Name',' O/R',' Ack. Receipt',' Date',' Description',' Category',' Credit',' Debit',' P. Method',' Chq. Date',' Chq. No.',' Bank Name',' Deposited'],
  ['0001',' Snow',' ',' ',' Thu Apr 12 20:24:41 GMT+08:00 2018',' H.O.A. dues for month of April',' HOA Dues',' ',' 400.0',' ',' ',' ',' ',''],
  ['0002',' Two',' ',' ',' Thu Apr 12 20:24:41 GMT+08:00 2018',' H.O.A. dues for month of April',' HOA Dues',' ',' 400.0',' ',' ',' ',' ','' ],
  ['0003',' Three',' ',' ',' Thu Apr 12 20:24:41 GMT+08:00 2018',' H.O.A. dues for month of April',' HOA Dues',' ',' 400.0',' ',' ',' ',' ','' ],
  ['0004',' Four',' ',' ',' Thu Apr 12 20:24:41 GMT+08:00 2018',' Monthly accrued interest @ 12% per annum (1% per month) on ageing balance more than 3 months.',' Int. Charge',' ',' 4.0',' ',' ',' ',' ','' ],
  ['0004',' Four',' ',' ',' Thu Apr 12 20:24:42 GMT+08:00 2018',' H.O.A. dues for month of April',' HOA Dues',' ',' 400.0',' ',' ',' ',' ','' ],
  ['0005',' Five',' ',' ',' Thu Apr 12 20:24:42 GMT+08:00 2018',' Monthly accrued interest @ 12% per annum (1% per month) on ageing balance more than 3 months.',' Int. Charge',' ',' 8.0',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '],
  ['0005',' Five',' ',' ',' Thu Apr 12 20:24:42 GMT+08:00 2018',' H.O.A. dues for month of April',' HOA Dues',' ',' 400.0',' ',' ',' ',' ','' ],
  ['0006',' Six',' ',' ',' Thu Apr 12 20:24:43 GMT+08:00 2018',' Monthly accrued interest @ 12% per annum (1% per month) on ageing balance more than 3 months.',' Int. Charge',' ',' 12.0',' ',' ',' ',' ','' ],
  ['0006',' Six',' ',' ',' Thu Apr 12 20:24:43 GMT+08:00 2018',' H.O.A. dues for month of April',' HOA Dues',' ',' 400.0',' ',' ',' ',' ','' ]
]

let filtered = arr.filter(e => e[0] == '0004')

console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: Taki, please explain why I can't make your code run? When I slap it in an empty new function on app-script and try to save it, there is an error when saving - missing ';' before first line. I change let to var which solves that, but then syntax error on 2nd line (filter). Even I add ';' to the end of each line.

This is Javascript right? Why no ';' at the end of each line and how come it works here in the snippet? Thanks.

Comment: yes it is javascript, and semicolons `;` are optional , i don't know why you're having trouble though, can you provide more details on the environment you're working on ?

Comment: It's the Google Apps-Script console, connected to the Google Sheet I'm working on. It uses plain Javascript. I copied your code to a new function. Maybe it's the => that Google's complaining about? Is there an alternative to that?

Comment: this `arr.filter(e => e[0] == '0004')` is an abbreviation for `arr.filter(function(e){ return  e[0] == '0004'})` and it shouldn't be a problem, what exactly does the error say ?

Comment: Substituting that line for its counter part you supplied did the trick. All working now and it works on my original object too, without having to alter the object. Thank you sir.

Comment: Looks like I spoke too soon Taki. Worked in testing with explicitly stated search key '0004' but when I finally started trying to pass a value in as a variable to replace that it can't see the passed in value (even I confirm in line above using ui.alert(a), the value is present: The modified line looks like this: var myTrans = allTrans.filter(function(e, a){ return e[0] == a}). Is there a way to make it accept a variable?

Comment: you don't need to pass it, just declare it outside like : `var a='004' ; var myTrans = allTrans.filter(function(e){ return e[1] == a})`

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that your array is valid (with quotes around the values), you can simply filter it this way :

```js
const bigArray = [
 ["Account No.", "Acc. Name", "O/R, Ack. Receipt", "Date", "Description", "Category", "Credit", "Debit", "P. Method", "Chq. Date", "Chq. No.", "Bank Name", "Deposited"],
 ["0001", "Snow", , , "Thu Apr 12 20:24:41 GMT+08:00 2018", "H.O.A. dues for month of April","HOA Dues", , "400.0", , , , , ],
 ["0002", "Two", , , "Thu Apr 12 20:24:41 GMT+08:00 2018", "H.O.A. dues for month of April", "HOA Dues", , "400.0", , , , , ],
 ["0003", "Three", , , "Thu Apr 12 20:24:41 GMT+08:00 2018", "H.O.A. dues for month of April", "HOA Dues", , "400.0", , , , , ]
]

let filtered = bigArray.filter( subArray => subArray.includes("0002") )

console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: I didn't choose your answer Jeremy because this will search the entire object and may match telephone numbers, etc., Appreciate your input though.

Comment: It won't search the entire array because `includes` stops at the first matched occurrence. And it won't match any phone number unless someone's phone number is _exactly_ "0002". Besides, his solution doesn't limit searching only the first element in the array.

Comment: Noted on this Jeremy. I apologize for casting dispersions on your code. :-)