# Turning a Google Sheets Apps-Script Javascript object into a valid array?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script

I'm using getDataRange().getValues() to copy data from a Google sheet to an array which I can work with.

i thought I had been successful and have been workng with several datasets in this manner until now, however I attempted to use filter() on the array without success. Stack Overflow informed me that the array is not valid (it's just a Javascript object, but not an array).

The format is like this:

```
[
  [a1,a2,a3,a4],
  [b1,b2,b3,b4],
  [c1,c2.c3,c4]
]
```

*Note the missing apostrophes around each value.*

This is the code I'm using to create the object:

```
var allTrans = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there away to get the sheet values into a valid array or does anyone have any suggestion on the best way to wrap each value into quotes, so I can use filter on it?

This is related to a question I asked earlier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49857884/how-to-filter-matching-records-in-a-multidimentional-unindexed-javascript-array).

Ideally, I'd like the structure of resulting array to the same as above, since I've already written nearly 1,000 lines of code accessing the array using **alltrans[i][0]** (etc.). Thanks,

Comment: Can you share a sample spreadsheet with some data? Or are you mutilating/ altering the array in some other part of your script?

Comment: I'm only accessing the array in other parts of my scripts, not altering it. It's nearly 11pm here and need to sleep but I'll look at creating something I can share in the morning if needed. Thanks.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the array. Just because you can't see the quotes doesn't mean it's not there. You're probably doing the  filter wrong.

Comment: `Range#getValues()` is 100% returning you a valid Javascript array of Javascript arrays. If you are previewing the structure with `Logger.log`, stop, and use the Stackdriver `console.log` (then View -> Stackdriver Logs).

Answer (score 0):

It comes down to the syntax of how you apply your array. Someone else explained it well in this post: [How to filter an array of arrays (Google app script)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40849369/how-to-filter-an-array-of-arrays-google-app-script)